# Solution in hackerrank doesn't match

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-programming

I have solved the [Maximum Subarray](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maxsubarray) problem in HackerRank. 
it runs fine on codeblocks. But when I submit my solution, it gives a different answer in their console.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
int no,n,i;

cin>>no;
while(no--){

    int arr[100001]={0},arr1[100001]={0};
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>arr[i];

    arr1[0]=arr[0];
    int maxi=arr[0];

    for(i=1;i<n;i++){

        if(arr[i]+arr1[i-1]>arr[i]){
            arr1[i]=arr[i]+arr1[i-1];
        }
        else{
            arr1[i]=arr[i];
        }

        if(arr1[i]>maxi)
            maxi=arr1[i];
    }


    cout<<maxi<<" ";


    sort(arr,arr+n);
    int sum=0,i=n-1;
    while(arr[i]>0)
        sum+=arr[i--];

    if(sum==0)
    sum=arr[i];
    cout<<sum<<endl;

   }
   return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to correct my solution?

Comment: Share the outputs that you are getting on local machine and hackerrank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(arr[i]>0)
    sum+=arr[i--];
```

This can be garbage because i can go below 0.

For example, for the input

```
1
4
1 2 3 4
```

I see that your code outputs `10 14` wrongly.